# How to keep root level `export` when building with Vite in format `esm`

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, vite

it's a pretty simple requirement,

I hope the building result can keep the `export` statement in main.js,

so that I can load the script in a `<script type="module">` tag and get the exported variable.

but now, the building result keeps import statement, but the `export` `export default` is lost.

any idea ?

```
// entry point 'main.js'
import { mount } from "./lifecycle";
export {mount};
export default mount();
```

```
// vite-config.js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  build:{
    rollupOptions: {
      treeshake: false,
      output: {
        format: 'es'
      }
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*get the exported variable.*"

Comment: Your entrypoint module won't be imported anywhere, so why would it need to export anything?

Comment: @Bergi it sounds a little bit wired, but I do have this scenario,  this project should be able to open in a new page, and it also needs to be opened in a micro-web project, in which I need to get the ```mount``` function, so that I can load this app in the micro-web page.

Answer (score 3):

What you are probably looking for is [`preserveEntrySignatures`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#preserveentrysignatures). Set it to something other than `false` to keep the exports.

```js
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  build:{
    rollupOptions: {
      preserveEntrySignatures: 'strict',
      // ...
    }
```

By default Vite will set this to `false` unless it is operating in library or SSR mode.